# Classifying Object Based on Mean IR Values

Tags: image-classification, ecognition, reflectance

While Developing rule sets using e-Cognition for object classification for say; Landsat 7 images what are the threshold conditions to classify water, building, agriculture land & bare soil according to IR values? Why water have less IR values compared to others? Is that due to the factor that water have only reflectance below 0.8 as shown below in figure 1. In the same manner can vegetation and soil values of reflectance be assigned as between 0.6-1.4 (due to their high reflectance as shown in figure 2) & >1.6 respectively?

[image]

[image]